# Can't open Project Structure dialog in Android Studio 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When I try to open the Project Structure dialog in Android Studio (I'm using 4.1 on macOS), I get a process called "Fetching build models" running, but nothing happens. Any successive attempt results in one additional "Fetching build models" process (i.e. I get "2 processes running...", then "3 processes running..." and so forth) - still with nothing happening, and in particular with the Project Structure dialog not appearing. What does appear is a small error icon at the corner: the first time with a `NoClassDefFoundError`, and later invocations with `NullPointerExceptoin` citing "cannot reset configurable".

Full details of first error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/resolve/constants/evaluate/ParseUtilsKt
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.kotlin.KotlinDslParser.extractValue(KotlinDslParser.kt:155)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslLiteral.lambda$produceValue$0(GradleDslLiteral.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:880)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslLiteral.produceValue(GradleDslLiteral.java:58)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.CachedValue.updateValue(CachedValue.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.CachedValue.getValue(CachedValue.java:53)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslSimpleExpression.getValue(GradleDslSimpleExpression.java:119)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.ext.GradlePropertyModelImpl.extractAndGetValueType(GradlePropertyModelImpl.java:526)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.ext.GradlePropertyModelImpl.getValueType(GradlePropertyModelImpl.java:100)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.ext.PropertyUtil.resolveModel(PropertyUtil.java:140)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.ext.ResolvedPropertyModelImpl.resolveModel(ResolvedPropertyModelImpl.java:258)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.ext.ResolvedPropertyModelImpl.getValueType(ResolvedPropertyModelImpl.java:50)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.model.meta.PropertyModelUtilsKt.asInt(PropertyModelUtils.kt:50)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.model.android.PsAndroidModuleDefaultConfigDescriptors$versionCode$4.invoke(PsAndroidModuleDefaultConfigDescriptors.kt:186)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.model.android.PsAndroidModuleDefaultConfigDescriptors$versionCode$4.invoke(PsAndroidModuleDefaultConfigDescriptors.kt:50)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.model.meta.PropertyModelUtilsKt.getParsedValue(PropertyModelUtils.kt:126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.model.meta.ModelPropertyCoreImpl.getParsedValue(ModelSimplePropertyImpl.kt:200)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.model.meta.ModelPropertyKt.getValue(ModelProperty.kt:74)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.configurables.ui.properties.SimplePropertyEditor.reload(SimplePropertyEditor.kt:330)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.configurables.ui.properties.SimplePropertyEditor.<init>(SimplePropertyEditor.kt:348)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.configurables.ui.properties.SimplePropertyEditorKt.simplePropertyEditor(SimplePropertyEditor.kt:361)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.configurables.ui.PropertiesUiModelKt.simplePropertyEditor(PropertiesUiModel.kt:144)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.configurables.android.modules.AndroidModuleRootConfigurableKt$defaultConfigPropertiesModel$3.invoke(AndroidModuleRootConfigurable.kt:90)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.configurables.android.modules.AndroidModuleRootConfigurableKt$defaultConfigPropertiesModel$3.invoke(AndroidModuleRootConfigurable.kt)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.configurables.ui.PropertyUiModelImpl.createEditor(PropertiesUiModel.kt:116)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.configurables.ui.PropertyUiModel$DefaultImpls.createEditor$default(PropertiesUiModel.kt:65)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.configurables.ui.properties.ConfigPanel.initializeEditors(ConfigPanel.kt:65)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.configurables.ui.properties.ConfigPanel.getComponent(ConfigPanel.kt:56)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.configurables.ui.AbstractTabbedMainPanel.ensureSelectedTabComponentInstantiated(AbstractTabbedMainPanel.kt:70)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.configurables.ui.AbstractTabbedMainPanel.addNotify(AbstractTabbedMainPanel.kt:77)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at com.intellij.ui.JBSplitter.addNotify(JBSplitter.java:111)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.MasterDetailsComponent$3.addNotify(MasterDetailsComponent.java:128)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at com.intellij.ui.JBSplitter.addNotify(JBSplitter.java:111)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4741)
    at javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(JRootPane.java:757)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2776)
    at java.awt.Window.addNotify(Window.java:770)
    at java.awt.Dialog.addNotify(Dialog.java:753)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.addNotify(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:638)
    at java.awt.Window.pack(Window.java:807)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:649)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:437)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1685)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1644)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGet(DialogWrapper.java:1658)
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.dialog.ProjectStructureConfigurable.showDialog(ProjectStructureConfigurable.kt:336)
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.dialog.ProjectStructureConfigurable.showPlace(ProjectStructureConfigurable.kt:277)
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.dialog.ProjectStructureConfigurable.show(ProjectStructureConfigurable.kt:293)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.actions.AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.showAndroidProjectStructure(AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.java:67)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.actions.AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.actionPerformed(AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:280)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher$1.performAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:609)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.lambda$processAction$3(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:670)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:669)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:619)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processActionOrWaitSecondStroke(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:516)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.inInitState(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:470)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:219)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$new$5(IdeEventQueue.java:233)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:805)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(IdeKeyboardFocusManager.java:40)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4770)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:974)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchKeyEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:900)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:841)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:449)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:741)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:448)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:831)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:502)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.constants.evaluate.ParseUtilsKt PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 201.8743.12.41.6858069] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@7bf47206
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:115)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    ... 133 more
```

Full details of subsequent errors:

```
cannot reset configurable

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.MasterDetailsComponent.clearChildren(MasterDetailsComponent.java:428)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.MasterDetailsComponent.disposeUIResources(MasterDetailsComponent.java:417)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.configurables.BasePerspectiveConfigurable.reset(BasePerspectiveConfigurable.kt:213)
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.dialog.ProjectStructureConfigurable.reset(ProjectStructureConfigurable.kt:399)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.reset(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:166)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.lambda$createConfigurableComponent$4(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:118)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:894)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.compute(ReadAction.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.createConfigurableComponent(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:105)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.lambda$create$0(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:894)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.compute(ReadAction.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.create(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:53)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor$1.create(ConfigurableEditor.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor$1.create(ConfigurableEditor.java:48)
    at com.intellij.ui.CardLayoutPanel.createValue(CardLayoutPanel.java:73)
    at com.intellij.ui.CardLayoutPanel.select(CardLayoutPanel.java:101)
    at com.intellij.ui.CardLayoutPanel.select(CardLayoutPanel.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor.init(ConfigurableEditor.java:100)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SingleSettingEditor.<init>(SingleSettingEditor.java:29)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialog.<init>(SettingsDialog.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.dialog.ProjectStructureConfigurable$showDialog$dialog$1.<init>(ProjectStructureConfigurable.kt:296)
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.dialog.ProjectStructureConfigurable.showDialog(ProjectStructureConfigurable.kt:296)
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.dialog.ProjectStructureConfigurable.showPlace(ProjectStructureConfigurable.kt:277)
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.dialog.ProjectStructureConfigurable.show(ProjectStructureConfigurable.kt:293)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.actions.AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.showAndroidProjectStructure(AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.java:67)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.actions.AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.actionPerformed(AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:280)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher$1.performAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:609)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.lambda$processAction$3(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:670)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:669)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:619)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processActionOrWaitSecondStroke(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:516)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.inInitState(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:470)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:219)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$new$5(IdeEventQueue.java:233)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:805)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(IdeKeyboardFocusManager.java:40)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4770)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:974)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchKeyEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:900)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:841)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:449)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:741)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:448)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:831)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:502)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Note: this happens to me in one specific Android project; in another project I'm working on with the same Android Studio version on the same machine I can open the Project Structure dialog without a problem - but I've got no idea what causes that difference.

Any idea why that happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else faces a similar problem and stumbles upon this, by now I've managed to solve the issue in two different ways - but note that in the meantime I've also updated Android Studio to 4.1.1, but didn't try to just open the project the way it was, so I can't tell if it's this upgrade which solved the issue, or if it was actually necessary to apply either one of the following alternatives:

- One option: delete your `.idea` directory and import the project into Android Studio anew (in my case I did it by cloning the Git repository, where, with the exception of two files - `gradle.xml` and `codeStyles/Project.xml` - the `.idea` directory is Git-ignored).
- Another option: open the project by telling Android Studio to *import* it rather than to *open* it (I'm not sure what difference that makes, if at all, but - at least in combination with upgrading to 4.1.1 - this has solved the problem).

I've still got no idea what caused the problem in the first place, and whatever it was, it's obviously a bug in Android Studio (at least in 4.1.0), but at least now I can edit my "project structure" through the dialog again. (By the way, I'd be much happier doing all the configuration directly in the Gradle build configuration script myself, but it seems it's far easier to come across explanations of how to do stuff in the Project Structure dialog than how to do it in Gradle... But that's another issue.)

Comment: This does not answer the question of why it happens, but does offer fixes. I'll accept it, as no other answers have been posted.